# Modifying Django's pre_save/post_save Data

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm having a hard time to grasp this post_save/pre_save signals from django.

What happens is that my model has a field called `status` and when a entry to this model is added/saved, it's status must be changed accordingly with some condition.

My model looks like this:

```
 class Ticket(models.Model):    
    (...)   
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=OFFERT_STATUS, default='O')
```

And my signal handler, configured for pre_save:

```
def ticket_handler(sender, **kwargs):
   ticket = kwargs['instance']
   (...)
   if someOtherCondition:
       ticket.status = 'C'
```

Now, what happens if I put a`ticket.save()` just bellow this last line `if` statement is a huge iteration black hole, since this action calls the signal itself. And this problem happens in both `pre_save` and `post_save`.

Well... I guess that the capability of altering a entry before (or even after) saving it is pretty common in django's universe. So, what I'm doing wrong here? Is the Signals the wrong approach or I'm missing something else here?

Also, would it be possible to, once this pre_save/post_save function is triggered, to access another model's instance and change a specific row entry on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Signals are not a proper approach for updating fields in the same model prior to save. Override the model's save method instead of using a signal for this case.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    status = whatever....
    super(Ticket, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

For updates to other models, signals are a great approach because you can easily decouple your models. Specifically, you can add a pre_/post_save signal to trigger actions without the need to modify the code of the saved model (which could reside in another application from a third party).

Comment: Even for this case described in the last paragraph, in which I want to access and alter an entry on other model?

Comment: For that, signals are the good approach, your models will be more decoupled

Comment: BTW I also use signals for post-save actions when e.g. I require the model to already have an ID (for example when I use the ID to calculate some other field which is key based on a hash of the object's ID)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Carles that this may belong in a `save()`. When you *must* do this with signals, make sure you have a very tight condition around the `save()`. Your test could be rewrtitten as:

```
   if someOtherCondition and ticket.status != 'C':
       ticket.status = 'C'
       ticket.save()
```

You won't get into infinite recursion with the test done this way.

Comment: Indeed, without adding this save() call, my changed fields on the User model are not being saved. Seems to be due to a frozen_set being passsed to the pre_save() hook which means other fields cannot be altered?

Comment: Can't say. I did a quick search on Django and `frozenset`s and only found [this fixed ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24521) from 2 years ago.